# How to get values from object?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I have one class as an interface "IClass" which is receiving an object only, no return type :

```
    public interface IClass
    {
        void OnEventReceived(EventData ev);
    }
```

Now I pass the interface class object in constructor of another class "Caller"

```
    public Caller(IClass evObjParm)
    {
        //pass parameters
    }
```

this class uses the information stored in `evObjParm`. However I am interested in only some of the information stored in evObjParm. How I can get a subset of that information?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to extract arbitrary information from the EventData passed down to the event handler.

```
public struct EventData 
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public int position;
    public string auxiliary;
}

...
void OnEventReceived(EventData ev) {
    var infoRecord = ev.Select(x => new { x.name, x.id }).ToArray();
    ...
}
```

Comment: there are events in    OnEventReceived(EventData ev)

Comment: You'll have to clarify the question - say what kind of information exactly you want extracted. If you provide your own example of EventData that would be most helpful. That said, nothing prevents you from extracting the events from EventData as well - if that's what you want to extract.

Comment: OnEventReceived(EventData ev) when i run this project this object goes in different classes adn get some use full information like user id, name, age, dOB, address adn many other. that information is in side in this object. when i will pass this object to constructor how i can get just name and address.

Answer (score 1):

Either this is a very simple or very complicated question, but why don't you save only what you need?

```
public string Name {get; set;}
public DateTime Time {get; set;}

public Caller(IClass evObjParm)
{
    Name = evObjParm.Name;
    Time = evObjParm.Time;
}
```

Or perhaps you are asking for something like (more likely):

```
public Caller(IClass evObjParm)
{
    if(evObjParm is ClassA)
    {
        var a = evObjParm as ClassA;
        var name = a.Name;
        // ...
    }
    if(evObjParm is ClassB) { /* ... */ }
    // ...
}
```